# Many Input masks for the same input field

Tags: primefaces, masking

Is it possible to have different input mask patterns for the same input field? I am trying to validate a Postal Code field where the user can enter codes of the format AA9A , AA9 9AA and a few more.
I am using PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/normanzb/chuanr/

This tools support multiple patterns. you can even create a custom matching.

take a look at the demo, click "patterns"
http://normanzb.github.com/chuanr/.